# How to combine different questions of questionnaire into a single variable?

Tags: spss, survey, likert

I have used a 48 item questionnaire - a Likert scale - with 5 points (strongly agree - strongly disagree). The questionnaire contains 6 categories and each category has 8 questions. 8 items correspond to one variable which means that we have 6*8 = 48 questions in questionnaire.

How do I combine the 8 different items into one variable, so that we will have 6 variables?

How can I combine different items into one variable in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

If the categories are reliable, then you can just add the question scores to a total category score. To assess the reliability of a category, you can use Cronbach's alpha. The gist is as follows. If the questions per category do not correlate, then the questions each measure something different. Adding the question scores would be like adding random noise. This would not be a reliable score. For more information see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach's_alpha